# Meaning of "e" and "ee" in "Id" column of `fdisk -l`?

Tags: fdisk

I am trying to inspect an SD card which may or may not be failing, on Ubuntu 14.04. This is the output I get from `fdisk -l`:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
...
Disk identifier: 0x000a671b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *          63      144584       72261    e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/sdc2          144585     7553023     3704219+   e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
```

What I find weird is the "`e`" in the "`Id`" column - trying to remind myself what I usually get there, I found https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-check-boot-path-command/, and "`Id`" should be like "`82`" (for linux swap), "`83`" (I guess this was ext3) etc. But now, here I see "`e`", and for some other drives of mine, "`ee`".

So what is the meaning of "`e`" and "`ee`" in the "`Id`" column of `fdisk -l` output? I tried looking in `man fdisk`, but could find explanations there...

Answer (score 4):

The id is the partition type (or id) which is used to specify the filesystem type of the partition.

[This link](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-1.html) shows that `e` or `0e` means `WIN95: DOS 16-bit FAT, LBA-mapped` and `ee` means `Indication that this legacy MBR is followed by an EFI header`.

You can also find more information about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type)

Comment: On Linux, command `l` run from `fdisk` lists all supported partition types.